# How to set "org.w3c.css.sac.parser" system property?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, sac

In this [ParserFactory.java](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/branches/gumbo_alpha/modules/thirdparty/batik/sources/org/w3c/css/sac/helpers/ParserFactory.java)

```
String className = System.getProperty("org.w3c.css.sac.parser");
if (className == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("No value for sac.parser property");  //line 35
} else {
    return (Parser)(Class.forName(className).newInstance());
}
```

When I run this [DemoSAC.java](http://www.w3.org/TR/SAC/DemoSAC.java) file as Java Application in Eclipse, I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: No value for sac.parser property
at org.w3c.css.sac.helpers.ParserFactory.makeParser(ParserFactory.java:35)
```

What exactly is the "org.w3c.css.sac.parser" property?  How do I set it under Windows?  What should I set it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify code, you can also set a Java property in Eclipse's Java launch configuration dialog.  You specify a "VM option" in the "Arguments" tab .  To set the property to "org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser" as suggested by javamonkey79, you would specify:

-Dorg.w3c.css.sac.parser=org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to provide an interface implementation. Per this link [here](http://markmail.org/message/g4kx5po7gr2nzttg), this is one way to do it:

- get the flute parser [here](http://www.w3.org/2002/06/flutejava-1.3.zip)
- add it to your build path
- add this to the DemoSAC class (before the getProperty call):

  System.setProperty("org.w3c.css.sac.parser",
                       "org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser");

I don't know why it is doing this reflection based instantiation to begin with, perhaps bypassing ParserFactory and returning a new instance of the flute parser would be cleaner altogether?